# Set a default ref value on React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So my code looks like so:

```
stockconfirmbuy: function(){
  var totalbuyval = this.refs.stockpriceref.innerHTML * this.refs.stockdnum.value;    
    return (<div>
         <input type="number" value="1" ref="stockdnum" /> 
         <p>Your Total:</p>
         <p>${totalbuyval}</p>              
</div>);
},
```

My problem here is that I get a `Cannot read property 'value' of undefined` error. This refers to my `input type="number"`.

However, I have been trying to give my input a default value so that this does not occur. I gave it a default `value=1`, but this does not seem to satisfy the ref.

So I am wondering what I need to do to set a default ref value. Or should I be using state?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should absolutely be using state here, set default state value with [`getInitialState()`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#getinitialstate) for both `stockdnum` and `stockpriceref`

You then can render the value from state, e.g. `<input type="number" value={this.state.stockdnum}/>`. Note that this will cause the input to be read-only unless you set up an `onChange` to update state. [Read more about this here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html#controlled-components)

I doubt you need refs at all for this, and in fact you should avoid them if possible. They're more for providing raw DOM refs to non-React APIs (e.g. jQuery or TweenLite or something)

Also, string refs as you are using them there will [likely be removed in the future](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html#the-ref-string-attribute) anyway

Answer (score 2):

> I have been trying to give my input a default value so that this does
>   not occur

you can do something like this :

```
var defaultRef = typeof this.refs.stockdnum.value !== "undefined" ? this.refs.stockdnum.value : defaultValue;
var totalbuyval = this.refs.stockpriceref.innerHTML * defaultRef;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can you defaultValue attribute

```html
<input type="text" ref={nameRef} name="name" placeholder="Enter name..." defaultValue={...yourvalue} />
```

Answer (score -1):

I solved it by assigning the initial value in componentDidMount. I was receiving initial value through props. Take a look.

[image: Code Preview]